# Android data receiving in back ground

Tags: android

In my application i need to get data from internet. So that i need to process a method in back ground from splash screen and after splash screen disappear too.

```
public class Splash_Screen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash__screen);

        ProgressBar p_bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                data_receiver receiver=data_receiver.getInstance();
                receiver.access_parser();

            }
        });
        thread.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent main_window=new Intent(com.burusoth1990.advertise.Splash_Screen.this,com.burusoth1990.advertise.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(main_window);

            }
        }, 5000);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_splash__screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

splash screen need to work for 5 seconds but receiver.access_parser() method need to work in back ground after splash screen activity exits and new activity open. this is my code but it throws error.

Comment: Use android services that is the best way to background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background operations in Android, especially those that are not directly tied to a single activity, are typically implemented using a *Service* or *IntentService*. See these documentation pages:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: I would suggest IntentService if that fits the needs. It is somewhat simpler, as it is started once and keeps running till it is done. The framework handles everything considering binding etc. for you.